# 3ds max / maxscript: Simple models with weird normals

Tags: 3dsmax, normals, maxscript

I am re-posting a question from the 3ds max forum to increase visibility (and enable file attachment). Currently, I am struggling with normals for two models:

- First model (model1.zip): Why does the following command return different normals in world space? All objects have the same geometry (but different node & offset transforms), so I would expect the normals in world space to be the same. Maxscript command:

> coordsys world getnormal $ 1

- Second model (model2.zip): Why is the length of the normal not equal to unity? After resetting the transform the normals are ok. But I want to avoid the resetX command at all cost. Same maxscript command as above:

> coordsys world getnormal $ 1

Files and original post can be found here:

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/3ds-max-programming/simple-models-with-weird-normals/td-p/8410040

Thanks a lot for your help!

PS: Sorry for the code formatting...maxscript is not recognized as code.

Comment: I didn't look at the files but are you sure its not because there is rotation and/or scale in the node/offset transforms?

Comment: Yes, there are node and offset transforms (translation, rotation and scale). However, to my understanding, this should not have an influence as we explicitly specify the reference coordinate system to 'world'. Or is my understanding of 'coordsys world' wrong?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  Its been a number of years since I've worked with Max, but I think this could easily be a bug with how specified/explicit normals are transformed into world space.  If max naively multiplies the normals by the transform matrix hierarchy so that rotation is correct, it could potentially screw up the scale if scale is present.  I wouldn't be surprised at all if this only happened for specified/explicit normals, and smoothing group based normals came out ok.

Comment: Hm, that sounds pretty awful...but it is unfortunately not the first time I hear a comment about buggy transformation issue in max. Would you have a chance to double-check the files? I would really appreciate that...and already thank you very much for your insights so far!